# react-native - onPressIn Event not working on component TextInput

Tags: react-native

This code below is example from react native documentation, the problem is onPressIn does not work as expected, do I understand the meaning of onPressIn event or there is ongoing problem with onPressIn and OnPressOut event listeners, on component TextInput.

Expo Snack - [Here](https://snack.expo.io/@bekabatmanashvili/textinput)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: change `onPressin` on `onPressIn` (capital letter I).
The next error I noticed was at: `const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);` the initial value should not be null but as suggests reac-native docs "string" . I suggest you just put an empty string there.